# Identical function on comparing data frame against a value

Tags: r, data-manipulation

```
id <- 3
nobs <- 243

A3 <- data.frame(id, nobs)
B3 <- 243

> A3
  id nobs
1  3  243
```

I'm trying to compare the A3's nobs, which is 243 against B3

as

```
identical(A3$nobs[[1]] == B3[[1]])
```

which giving me error

> Error in identical(A3$nobs[[1]] == B3[1])

**how do I compare a dataframes's column value against a no?**

Comment: `A3$nobs == B3` or `A3$nobs[1] == B3` or `A3$nobs[1] == B3[1]` ?

Comment: Or read the docs for `?identical` and use it properly: `identical(A3$nobs[1], B3)`.

Comment: Thanks @jogo @joran that helped me. In this case since B3 is vector of length 1 having value 243, same goes for nobs. So we have accessed it like B3[1]

Suppose we have a list as `B3<- as.list(243)` . _In this case how do we compare A3's nobs values against B3?_

Comment: Just use double brackets, i.e. `B3[[1]]`.